# LikEE js wont work in the following

Tags: add-on, forum

I came up with this odd issue. If i surf around my forum as usual, LikEE works, but when i come from outside of the site, or click internal links in forums,
this wont work:

{exp:likee:js skip_jquery="true"}

The javascript wont come, and the tag itself shows as is, in the sourcecode.
Because i dont know the actual java, i cant "hardcode" it into end of the head-tag, neither i dont know if that even work then, because dont know how LikEE actual works.

I know this should be and have done into channels, but i just cant see why it wont work nicely in forums also.

And i do not use this with all posts, just if there is attachment in first post. (yep, i know, if someone replies and add another attachment, then all replies between first and last post has like - dislike buttons).

But somehow i have feeling that there might be a way to get this working with forums also? Any ideas or has someone even tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Most add-ons that work on the rest of the site do not work in the forums module as the forum templates are not typically sent through the EE template engine. You do have the option of running the forums through standard EE templates as mention in the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/forum/other_features.html#running-the-forums-through-regular-templates) but even then not every add-on works properly.

Comment: Ups, forgot to mention that i do run forums via regular templates, it is a must, if you want to power up forums. Its just odd, that the javascript wont come up. And i really cant fituge out why that is.